# Non working Spark example in Scala, LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

I tried to implement [this example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/MulticlassLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample.scala) for multinomial logistic regression, but it doesn't recognize features that are being used. Probably some version mismatch. This part of code:

```
trainingSummary.falsePositiveRateByLabel.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (rate, label) =>
  println(s"label $label: $rate")
}
```

None of the members of `LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary` are being recognized, `falsePositiveRateByLabel` particulary in the given example. As well as other members later in code: `truePositiveRateByLabel`, `precisionByLabel`,...

When I go to implementation I can't find any similar members that I could use instead, I use mllib 2.11. What am I missing?

Comment: The example use the `ml` package, if you use `mllib` (older machine learning package in Spark) then there is a huge difference.

Comment: @Shaido I have both packages, ml and mllib, and I use ml since I copied example code. Does it work on your machine? Thanks!

Comment: I looked into it and added an answer, unfortunatly the only solution is to wait or build the source code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is a versioning issue. The [github code example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/MulticlassLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample.scala) you have given is for the current master branch of Spark where there has been some major changes in this part of the API.

What you have been following is what code in Spark 2.3 will look like. However, at this time, this version is not yet stable and available for download. This is what the [version 2.2 branch](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/MulticlassLogisticRegressionWithElasticNetExample.scala) of the same code example looks like:

```
val training = spark
  .read
  .format("libsvm")
  .load("data/mllib/sample_multiclass_classification_data.txt")

val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

// Fit the model
val lrModel = lr.fit(training)

// Print the coefficients and intercept for multinomial logistic regression
println(s"Coefficients: \n${lrModel.coefficientMatrix}")
println(s"Intercepts: ${lrModel.interceptVector}")
// $example off$

spark.stop()
```

In other words, the methods you are trying to use are not yet implemented in your Spark version.